# Why is the behaviour of subtracting characters implementation specific?

Tags: c, character-encoding

This statement:

```
if('z' - 'a' == 25)
```

is not guaranteed to evaluate in the same way. It is compiler dependent. Also, it is not guaranteed to be evaluated in the same way as this:

```
#if 'z' - 'a' == 25
```

even if both the preprocessor and compiler are run on the same machine. Why is that?

Comment: in the first case, the preprocessor does the work

Comment: The same as what? Are you comparing `#if 'z' - 'a' == 25`  with  `if('z' - 'a' == 25)` or are you asking why `'z' - 'a'` is not evaluated to the same constant on different implementations.

Comment: I am asking why is not evaluated to the same constant on different implementations. I mentioned clearly in my question evaluate not comparing. Answert from klutt is what I wanted. I have to wait certain periond of time to accept his answer that is why I'm waiting.

Comment: @wildpointerxx then the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The OP is asking about a direct quote from the standard — [N1570 §6.10.1p3,4 + footnote 168](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p3):

> ... the controlling constant expression is evaluated according to the rules of 6.6. ... This includes interpreting character constants, which may involve converting escape sequences into execution character set members. Whether the numeric value for these character constants matches the value obtained when an identical character constant occurs in an expression (other than within a #if or #elif directive) is implementation-defined.<sup>168</sup>
>
> [footnote 168] Thus, the constant expression in the following #if directive and if statement is not guaranteed to evaluate to the same value in these two contexts.
>
> ```
> #if 'z' - 'a' == 25
> if ('z' - 'a' == 25)
> ```

So, yes, it really isn't guaranteed.

To understand *why* it isn't guaranteed, first you need to know that the C standard doesn't require the character constants `'a'` and `'z'` to have the numeric values assigned to those characters by ASCII.  *Most* C implementations nowadays use ASCII or a superset, but there is another encoding called [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) that is still widely used (only on IBM mainframes, but there are still a lot of those out there).  In EBCDIC, not only do `'a'` and `'z'` have different values from ASCII, the alphabet isn't a contiguous sequence!  That's why the expression `'z' - 'a' == 25` might not evaluate true in the first place.

You also need to know that the C standard tries to maintain a distinction between the text encoding used for source code (the "source character set") and the text encoding that the program will use at runtime (the "execution character set").  This is so you can, at least in principle, take a program whose source encoded in ASCII text and run it unmodified on a computer that uses EBCDIC, just by cross-compiling appropriately; you don't have to convert the source text to EBCDIC first.

Now, the compiler has to understand both character sets if they're different, but historically, the C preprocessor ([translation phases](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) 1 through 4) and the "compiler proper" (phases 5 through 7) were two separate programs, and `#if` expressions are the only place where the preprocessor would have to know about the execution character set.  So, by making it implementation-defined whether the "execution character set" used by the preprocessor matches that used by the compiler proper, the standard licenses the preprocessor to do all its work in the *source* character set, making life a little bit easier back in 1989.

Having said all that, I would be very surprised to find a modern compiler that didn't make both expressions evaluate to the same value, even when the execution and source character sets are grossly incompatible.  Modern compilers tend to have *integrated* preprocessors -- phases 1 through 7 are all carried out by the same program -- and even if they don't, the engineering burden of specializing the preprocessor to match its execution character set to the compiler proper is trivial nowadays.

Comment: I didn't know EBCDIC is "still in wide use". The name EBCDIC so smells like punchcards to me that I usually only take it as a rather academic example (as with 36bit word machines or ternary)

Comment: There have been a few new encodings made in this millennium for backward-compatibility. The official UTF-EBCDIC (https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr16/) and Oracle’s UTFE both came out in 2002. They’re more for sending Unicode data safely through old systems that assume data is EBCDIC, though. Does anybody actually use them?

Comment: IBM’s z/OS XL C/C++ compiler is one that still assumes code page 1047 by default, but has options to change the character set for all—or some—of the source. In particular, the `CONVLIT` option might not affect all preprocessor directives, at least as of this version: (https://www-304.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc147307/$file/cbcux01_v2r3.pdf)

Comment: Not just the fact that EBCDIC isn't compatible with ASCII, but that it doesn't have the letters in a contiguous sequence, so something like `c - 'a'` (with  a lowercase letter in `c`) isn't as useful as with ASCII...

Comment: preprocessor / compiler / assembler still *are* separate executables with GCC.  The `gcc` front-end uses tmp files or pipes to send data between them.  I have no idea how it handles different source / target character sets, though.

Comment: I see 1500+ COBOL jobs listed on indeed.com, and that language is almost exclusively on mainframes, so they are still there. C is probably only an issue for admins that have to port utilities they use on UNIX systems to the mainframe.

Comment: @PeterCordes GCC has had an integrated preprocessor since version 3.0.  I should know; I wrote roughly 1/3 of it.  (It still installs a program named `cpp` for compatibility with old shell scripts, but that's actually a driver program like the `gcc` front end.)

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction.  I just assumed based on the behaviour of `-save-temps` (and that the assembler really is still separate unless that change recently), but it makes sense to still save a `.i` even if it never exists in real compilation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, the assembler is still separate last I heard (I haven't been active in GCC development for many years). `-save-temps` mode does indeed split it into two stages so it can generate an `.i` file, because `.i` files are useful - but look carefully at the `-v` output and you'll notice both stages are invoking `cc1`.

Answer (score 16):

Because not all computers use ascii or unicode.

In the past, a standard called ebcdic was common. In ebcdic 500 the value of `'z'` is 169 and the value of `'a'` is 130. The expression `'z'-'a'` would then evaluate to 39.

This explains why you cannot assume a certain value for an expression of the type `'a'` or even `'z'-'a'`. However, it does not explain why the two expressions in the Q are not guaranteed to be equal.

The preprocessor and the compiler are two different things. The preprocessor deals with the encoding used in the source code, while the compiler targets the machine you are compiling for. See zwol's answer for a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: Not only in the past, IBM mainframes use it all the time.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the standard permits the preprocessor and compiler proper to disagree on the value of the expression.

Comment: @zwol you probably misunderstood the (poorly asked) question (as I did at first). The OP makes clear what he wants in his last comment.

Comment: zwol is correct, I actually quoted my question while reading the C standard.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the other correct answers, a real-world example of a non-ASCII C compiler that’s still being used is [IBM’s z/OS XL C/C++](https://www-304.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc147307/$file/cbcux01_v2r3.pdf).  By default, it assumes that source files are in IBM code page 1047 (the version of EBCDIC with the same repertoire as Latin-1).  However, it has several different compiler options to support not only ASCII, but also “hybrid code,” or source files containing data in more than one encoding.  (These programs exist because MVS compilers required syntax statements to be in IBM-1047 encoding only.)

From the documentation, it looks like it would be possible to muck around with commands like `#pragma CONVLIT(suspend)` in a way that really would make those two statements evaluate differently on that compiler.  I don’t have a copy to test a MCVE on.