# Is there a way to check the uppercase and isalpha case for strings in an array?

Tags: c

```
while(1)
    {

        char buff[1000];
        printf("Enter the word: ");
        fgets(buff, 1000, stdin);
        if(!strcmp(buff, "\n"))//empty search then break the loop
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Exiting the program\n");
            break;
        }


        int error = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(buff[i] != '\0')
        {

            if(buff[i] >= 33 && buff[i] <= 96)
            {
                break;
            }

            error = 1;
            i++;
        }

        if(error == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please enter something containing only lower-case letters\n");
        }

        }
```

I expect the output of `hello World` to be `Please enter something containing only lower-case letters`, but I am not getting that error.
If I enter `World hello` I am getting the expected result which is, it prints the error message.

Is there a way to use isalpha for the whole array?

Comment: Please don't hard-code supposed character values in the code, especially one like `33` when isn't even alphabetical. You are looking for the range `'a'` to `'z'` and anything else is not a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not hard-code letter values but use the actual values. In this problem any letter outside the range `'a'` to `'z'` is invalid. But it is more portable to use the library functions `isalpha()` and `islower()` because the letters values are not guaranteed to be consecutive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1) {

        char buff[1000];
        printf("Enter the word: ");
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
        if(!strcmp(buff, "\n")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Exiting the program\n");
            break;
        }
        int error = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(buff[i] != '\0') {
            if(isalpha(buff[i]) && !islower(buff[i])) {
                error = 1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(error == 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please enter something containing only lower-case letters\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Program session

```
Enter the word: hello world
Enter the word: Hello world
Please enter something containing only lower-case letters
Enter the word: hello World
Please enter something containing only lower-case letters
Enter the word: hello, world!
Enter the word:
Exiting the program
```

Comment: PS: it would have been simpler to use `if(isupper(buff[i]))` to disallow any uppercase occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

There are library functions for checking upper and lowercase. They are called `isupper` and `islower`. Use them. Although its uncommon with `'a'` being something else than 97, it may happen. If you mean the letter `'a'` then use the character literal `'a'` instead of the number 97. Furthermore, the letters aren't even guaranteed to be consecutive, so `'z'-'a'` is not guaranteed to be evaluated to 22. However, digits are required to be consecutive so `'9'-'0'` will always evaluate to 9. But it is much safer to rely on library functions like `isalpha` and such. I wrote about encoding here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890148/6699433

To correct your bug, you need a proper condition. According to your question, it should print the error message if any of the characters is not either a lower case or a space. Furthermore, your code is overly complicated. Here is a solution:

```
int i = 0;
while(buff[i] != '\0') {
    if(!(islower(buff[i]) || isspace(buff[i]))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter something containing only lower-case letters\n");
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

> Is there a way to use isalpha for the whole array?

C does not have built in functionality for such things, but you can write your own mapper.

```
/* Apply function f on each of the elements in str and return false
 * if f returns false for any of the elements and true otherwise.
 */

bool string_is_mapper(const char *str, size_t size, int (*f)(int c))
{
    for(int i=0; i<size && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if(!f(str[i])) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now, you can use this mapper like this:

```
if(string_is_mapper(str, strlen(str), isupper)
     puts("All characters in str is upper case");
```

You can even write your own functions to plugin, as long as they fit this prototype:

```
int condition(int c);
```

Comment: Could those function be used for an array? Would it be possible for you to highlight how I can use those in my code?