# Char as Array index

Tags: arrays, c, char

Can someone explain me why the index of `cvorkommen` (`zeichen_c - '0'` works as an integer 4?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char cvorkommen [100] = {0};
  char zeichen_c = '4';

  cvorkommen[zeichen_c - '0']++
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: all arithmetic operations yield an `int` (or `unsigned`) or larger type... so `char - int` (your code -- [*try `sizeof '0'` to see for yourself that `'0'` is not a char*]) gives an `int`... `char - char` gives an `int`... `char + short` gives an `int`... `char * char` gives an `int` ...

Comment: `char` are basically integers, and to each integer is attributed a character

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46890093/6699433

Comment: @klutt Arithmetic on digits `'0'` to `'9'` specifically isn't implementation-defined. They are a special case.

Comment: @Lundin I know. That's why I didn't dupe it. It's releated.

Answer (score 3):

That works because you take the char `zeichen_c` which has the ASCII value of `'4'` (0x34) and subtract the ASCII value of `'0'` (0x30) from it. That leaves you with 0x4 which is a valid index of your array.

Comment: This isn't exclusive to ASCII. It also works on an EBCDIC machine since digits are continuous and ordered there too. It's just that it would be 0xF4 - 0xF0 = 4 there.

Comment: The answer is correct. I rather would like to add that `char` is basically just a 1 byte (8-bit) integer. It would have normal integer values (but the limit of the values is set, which is -128 to 127). All ASCII characters are simple integers. You could even see their integer values by using `printf` with format `%d`. This way, you could use `char` as a counter, just the way you would have it with `int` (but be sure that your counter always counts less than or equal to 127, or else you will end up doing overflow).

Comment: @user1234: limits for `char` are not set. In a lot of personal computers limits will be `-128` to `127`, but can also be `0` to `255`. In **ALL** computers limits are `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX` :-)

Answer (score 3):

For the 10 numeric digit characters the C standard *requires* them to be in sequence:

> **5.2.1 Character sets**
>
> 3 ... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Other characters, such as alphabet letters, are not required to be in sequence. The uppercase and lowercase ASCII character alphabet characters are in sequence, but the EBCDIC ones are not.

So to find the numeric value of a digit character, it is always safe to subtract the base case

```
char digit = '4';
int number = digit - '0';
```